# Complex group by function for normalizing data

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has `dstipv4` and `pkts` fields. I want to calculate STDEV of normalized `pkts` for each `dstipv4`. I write a query like this it but does not work — generating the error:

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

How to write a correct query?

```
SELECT dstipv4, STDEV((pkts-min(pkts))/(max(pkts)-min(pkts))) FROM flow
group by dstipv4
```

Comment: please provide DDL and some date and expected output.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? If yes, update your question with that error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how best to explain it, but your calculation as shown requires prescience on the part of the DBMS, and the error message is the DBMS telling you that it doesn't have the requisite foresight.

I think you need to calculate the MAX and MIN values in a sub-query:

```
SELECT f.dstipv4, STDEV((f.pkts - m.min_pkts) / (m.max_pkts - m.min_pkts))
  FROM flow AS f
  JOIN (SELECT dstipv4, MIN(pkts) AS min_pkts, MAX(pkts) AS max_pkts
          FROM flow
         GROUP BY dstipv4
       ) AS m
    ON f.dstipv4 = m.dstipv4
 GROUP BY f.dstipv4
```